# Why does't eth0 come up?

Tags: raspbian, pi-a

I have a model a on which I'm running raspbian from autumn 2013.

It was a model b DC powered wifi 3g router.

Now its a solar powered wifi 3g router

Swapped the SD card into the A from the B and booted

Everything is working except the E3131 USB 3G stick.

It appears to have mode switched, dmesg mentions eth0

```
[  158.234882] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[  158.335999] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1f01
[  158.336032] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  158.336052] usb 1-1.2: Product: HUAWEI HiLink
[  158.336068] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[  158.350264] scsi1 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  159.537804] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 7
[  160.284904] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
[  160.386329] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14db
[  160.386362] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  160.386379] usb 1-1.2: Product: HUAWEI HiLink
[  160.386393] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[  160.490051] cdc_ether 1-1.2:1.0: eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-bcm2708_usb-1.2, CDC Ethernet Device, 58:2c:80:13:92:63
[  160.492181] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
```

/etc/network/interfaces contains

```
auto lo
auto eth0
auto eth1
auto wlan0

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth1 inet dhcp

iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.99.254
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

there is mention of eth0, on usb, but isn't that BCM mean broadcom?

```
/sys/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/net/eth0
```

Any ideas why my network isn't coming up?

Comment: you mentioned Solar Powered. Did you try a different power source?

Comment: What exactly is the question? You have asked about As & Bs. What isn't working?